# Bad questions that received excellent answers

Tags: discussion

A few months ago I published some [data explorer queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/148108/bad-question-good-answer?minimumDifference=4&maximumScore=5) I'd developed that people seemed to appreciate. I had a funny idea today and I thought I'd share my results: the following query lists answers that scored at least 4 points more than questions with a maximum score of 5 points (feel free to input different thresholds if you like).

[Bad Question, Good Answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/148108/bad-question-good-answer?minimumDifference=4&maximumScore=5)

Keep up the good work everyone, and a special thanks to those of you who have shown the patience to provide serious answers to poorly asked questions.

EDIT: I just realized this isn't an entirely original idea. See the page for the [reversal badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) (which hasn't yet been awarded on CV). Perhaps we should change the thresholds for the reversal badge to reflect the more conservative voting here compared to the voting on SO

Comment: It's interesting. But I beg to differ with your characterization: most of those questions are not stupid. Apart from two notable exceptions, the questions that turn up in your query--where they have low votes, which not all do--tend not to be well *asked*: but there is thought behind them.

Comment: I was being a bit tongue in cheek, maybe my word choice wasn't entirely fair. For "stupider" questions, change the maximumScore parameter from 5 to -1 or lower.

Comment: Aren't the badge thresholds SE-wide?

Comment: How about a query for the most contentious questions/answers? Say min(upvotes,downvotes).

Comment: @Scortchi how's this? http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/150175/contentious-cv-questions?minUpVotes=3&minDownVotes=3

Comment: Fixed a bug in the sorting: http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/150179/contentious-cv-questions?minUpVotes=3&minDownVotes=3

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot.